# Table Sections aren't being displayed correctly in a Table View Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have two sections declared in my Storyboard on my TableViewController. In the corresponding swift class, I have:

```
     override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 6
}
```

because I have 2 sections and 6 rows. However, this is giving me continuous Index out of bounds errors which is annoying because the sections are being declared! Am I doing anything wrong at all?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Okay so this is my table view controller:

[image]

What I've written in my cellForRow... is:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Section \(indexPath.section) Row \(indexPath.row)"

    return cell


}
```

I am new to Swift so I'm not sure entirely if this is correct, but basically what I get (with the cellForRow commented out is only the first section.)

Does this help?

Comment: Could you add the code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: What's inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: It is rare to return a constant from `numberOfRowsInSection`; normally you return the count that comes from your source data array.

Comment: I've updated my post. Thanks.

Comment: If you are declaring 2 sections with 6 rows each then you don't need all those extra sections and rows in your table view storyboard.  You are implementing the data source so it should be dynamic

Comment: Are you sure about the dataSource outlet? Is it connected to this VC? I don't see any error... @bolnad is right, may be a conflict with your settings in storyboard.

Comment: One of my sections has 5 rows and the other one - just like on the image. Is there a way of declaring this? @bolnad

Comment: switch indexPath.section { case 0: return 5 case1: return 1 default: return 0 }

Comment: It sounds like you want to implement a static table view and make outlets to each item in the cells instead of make a dynamic table view

Comment: What I get @Marcolo is a screen with just the MY DETAILS section showing - all the navigation controllers I have linking from the individual cells cease to work, effectively it's just that section showing.

Comment: It is a static table view @bolnad.

Comment: Ah then no need to implement any of the data source stuff

Comment: Is there any reason why just the my details bit is the only thing showing? @Marcolo I'll try that code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a different numbers of rows per section you need to separate them, you can't return the total number:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section { 
    case 0: return 5 
    case 1: return 1 
    default: return 0 
    }
}
```

In the inspector window, if you have static content try to set it to dynamic, you need only one cell prototype.

[image]

Comment: so case 1 is section 1?

Comment: yes , 0 is the first one, 1 for the second etc... indexing start at 0

Comment: It's still showing me only the first one unfortunately

Comment: Yes I can imagine, this is only a part of the problem, but I really can't understand why it show only one section if you have declared 2...

Comment: Great, thank you @Marcolo. I'll have a look and see what the issue is.

Comment: Hi @Marcolo, found it out. If you are using static cells - you're not meant to  have a numberOfRowsInSection method. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Next time for a similar problem try put a print("functionName") inside the function just to confirm it is called, or a break point.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

Hi all, just in case anyone is interested in the answer:

In Swift, if you are using static cells, you're not meant to have a numberOfSectionsInTableView or numberOfRowsInSection as these are needed **only** if you are using a data source. If you want to use static cells, be sure to remove these two methods.

Source: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113394/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I set up my table view Smith multiple rows in multiple sections:

1) At the top of the ViewController class, create this struct and below it, create the variable

```
struct Objects {
    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects: [String]!
}

var objectsArray = [Objects]()
```

2) In ViewDidLoad, set the variable

```
objectsArray = [Objects(sectionName: "Find People", sectionObjects: ["Facebook", "Twitter", "Contacts"]), Objects(sectionName: "Your Account", sectionObjects: ["Edit Info", "Delete Account"]), Objects(sectionName: "Support", sectionObjects: ["Help", "Report a Problem", "Contact Us"]), Objects(sectionName: "App Info", sectionObjects: ["About", "Open Source Libraries", "Privacy Policy",  "Our Twitter", "Our Facebook"])]
```

3) For numberOfSectionsInTableView

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return objectsArray.count

}
```

4) For numberOfRowsInSection

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return objectsArray[section].sectionObjects.count

}
```

5) For cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

6) For setting the titleForHeaderInSection

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return objectsArray[section].sectionName

}
```

7) In order for any actions to happen when you the user taps on the cell, you must call didSelectRowAtIndexPath -> In my case, I have 4 sections (headers), so I must create 4 switches (cases start at 0, not 1). Then, for each section, I must set a case for each row in each section. Within that case, you can call whatever you want -- for example, you can perform a segue to another viewController. The default essentially refers to the else in an if else statement...as in, if all else fails, display an error to the user that something didn't work right. You can use the built in alertView, but I like to use SCLAlertView available on GitHub!

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if reachabilityStatus == kNOTREACHABLE {

        self.displayError("No Internet Connection", message: "Please connect to the internet before continuing")


    } else {

        switch(indexPath.section) {

        case 0:


            switch(indexPath.row) {

            case 0:

                // Find People through facebook -> test below

                print("Connect with FB")

                return


            case 1:

                // Find People through twitter -> test below

                print("Connect with Twitter")

                return

            case 2:

                // Find People through contacts -> test below

                print("Connect with Contacts")


                return

            default:

                self.displayError("Something Went Wrong", message: "We're sorry, it seems like we can't open that for you. Please try again.")

                return

            }

        case 1:

            switch(indexPath.row) {


            case 0:

                // Edit Account -> test below

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("editProfileSegue", sender: self)

                return


            case 1:

                // Delete Account -> test below

                print("Delete Account")

                return


            default:

                self.displayError("Something Went Wrong", message: "We're sorry, it seems like we can't open that for you. Please try again.")

                return



            }


        case 2:


            switch(indexPath.row) {

            case 0:

                // Help -> test below

                print("Help")

                return


            case 1:

                // Report a Problem -> test below

                print("Report Problem")

                return

            case 2:

                // Contact Us -> test below

                print("Contact Us")


                return

            default:

                self.displayError("Something Went Wrong", message: "We're sorry, it seems like we can't open that for you. Please try again.")

                return

            }


        case 3:


            switch(indexPath.row) {

            case 0:

                // About App -> test below

                print("About App")

                return


            case 1:

                // Open Source Libraries -> test below

                print("Open Source Libraries")

                return

            case 2:

                // Privacy Policy -> test below

                print("Privacy Policy")


                return

            case 3:

                // Our Twitter -> Test Below

                print("Our Twitter")

            case 4:

                // Our Facebook -> Test Below

                print("Our Facebook")


                return

            default:

               self.displayError("Something Went Wrong", message: "We're sorry, it seems like we can't open that for you. Please try again.")

                return

            }

        default:

            self.displayError("Something Went Wrong", message: "We're sorry, it seems like we can't open that for you. Please try again.")

            print("last error")

            return


        } // close section switch


    }

}
```

In your case, you only have 3 sections, so just play around with the code to see what works

Let me know if you need any help!